# Nuances of the “compact set is closed” proof

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

smart guys!
I am studying Mathematical Analysis by Rudin and got stuck with the proof “compact set is closed”. The particular thing that puzzles me is:
There is an intersection of a finite number of neighborhoods of *q* within *1/2d(p,q)*. I do not get why this intersection exists, or to put it differently, cannot be a null set, why it should necessarily contain elements. Or it does not distort the logic of the proof in general?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If they are all neighbourhoods of a point $q$, then all these sets contain $q$ and therefore their intersection also contains $q$.

Comment: Doesn't $q$ itself have to be in each neighborhood?  It would be very helpful if you'd provide more context for the terms used in your question by editing your question to include more of the proof.  For example, different definitions of closed are used in different contexts (although they turn out to be equivalent).  It would be helpful to see enough of the proof to know which definition Rudin is using.

Comment: If $0 < r< s$ then $q \in B_r{(q)}=\{x\in X|d(x,q) < r\}\subset \{x\in X|d(x,q) < s\} = B_s(q)$.  So $B_r(q)\cap B_s(q) = B_r(q)\ni q$

Comment: Actually, nitpick.  In Rudin the neighbor hoods are around $p$ and not $q$.  but it doesn't matter. $p$ is in each of the neighborhoods.  Rudin is assuming it is clear the finite intersection of neighborhoods (open balls) around $p$ will itself be a neighborhood (open ball) around $p$ with a radius equal to the minimum radius of the open balls being intersected.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but I got the answer to my question anyway. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is a theorem where using the metric is more confusing than helpful.

The key point is that a metric space is Hausdorff. Suppose $C$ is a compact subset of the Hausdorff topological space $X$ and suppose $x\notin C$.

For each $y\in C$, choose an open set $U_y$ and an open set $V_x$ such that

1. $y\in U_y$;
2. $x\in V_y$;
3. $U_y\cap V_y$.

This is guaranteed by the Hausdorff hypothesis.

Then $(U_y)_{y\in C}$ is an open cover of $C$ and therefore we have
$$
C\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^n U_{y_k}
$$
for some $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n\in C$. Then
$$
V=\bigcap_{k=1}^n V_{y_k}
$$
is an open neighborhood of $x$ and $V\cap C=\emptyset$. Therefore $x\notin\bar{C}$ and so $C$ is closed.

What's the path with metric spaces? Our $U_y$ will be of the form $B(y,r_y)$ (open ball centered at $y$, with radius $r_y$) and $V_y=B(x,r_y)$, where you can take $r_y=d(x,y)/2$. By the triangle inequality, $B(y,r_y)\cap B(x,r_y)=\emptyset$.

One can choose the finite set $\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n\}$ as before and the point is that
$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^n B(x,r_{y_k})
$$
is not necessarily an open ball centered at $x$, but it surely contains one, for instance $B(x,r)$, where $r=\min\{r_{y_1},r_{y_2},\dots,r_{y_n}\}$. Then, as before, $B(x,r)\cap C=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

If $U_1, \dots, U_n$ are neighborhoods of $q$, there exists $r_1, \dots, r_n >0$ such that for all $k$ we have $B(q,r_k) \subset U_k$. Therefore,
$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^n B(q,r_k) \subset \bigcap_{k=1}^n U_k
$$

but $\bigcap_{k=1}^n B(q,r_k) = B(q,r)$ where $r = \displaystyle \min_{1 \leq k\leq n} r_k > 0$
so $\bigcap_{k=1}^n U_k$ is a neighborhood of $q$.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think (I may be misrembering) that Rudin defines neighborhoods as $B(q,r_k)$ so we don't need the $U_i$...  I think.

Comment: I haven't read Rudin's book but yes in this case there is no need for the $U_k$. However, you will find that a neighborhood of a point $x$ is often defined as a set $U$ containing an open ball centered around $x$, i.e. a set $U$ for which there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset U$. Hence the $U_k$ I introduced in my answer

Comment: Understood.  I should have pointed out solely for the definitions within the context of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Rudin is taking it for granted that $U_{q_i}= B_{r_i}(p) = \{x\in X| d(p,x)< r_i\}$ are neighborhoods centered at $p$[1] then any finite intersection $U_{q_1} \cap U_{q_2} \cap ... \cap U_{q_n}= B_{r_1}(p) \cap B_{r_2} (p)\cap .....\cap B_{r_n} (p)$ will itself be a neighborhood centered at $p$ with a radius equal to the least radius of $\{r_1,..., r_n\}$.  That is $ B_{r_1}(p) \cap B_{r_2} (p)\cap .....\cap B_{r_n} (p)=B_{\min r_i}(p)$ and that $B_{\min r_i}(p)$ is not empty because it contains $p$.

It's easy to prove this claim.

If $\{r_1,....,r_n\}$ are a finite set of strictly positive values then there exist some least element, call it $\min r$.

If $x \in B_{r_1}(p) \cap B_{r_2} (p)\cap .....\cap B_{r_n} (p)$ then $x \in B_{r_i}(p)$ for all $r_i$ and in particular $x \in B_{\min r}(p)$ so $B_{r_1}(p) \cap B_{r_2} (p)\cap .....\cap B_{r_n} (p)\subset B_{\min r}(p)$.

And if $x\in B_{\min r}(p)$ then $d(x,p)< \min r \le r_i$ for all $r_i$ so $x\in B_{r_i}(p)$ for all $B_{r_i}(p)$ so $x \in B_{r_1}(p) \cap B_{r_2} (p)\cap .....\cap B_{r_n} (p)$.  So $B_{\min r}(p) \subset B_{r_1}(p) \cap B_{r_2} (p)\cap .....\cap B_{r_n} (p)$.

So $B_{r_1}(p) \cap B_{r_2} (p)\cap .....\cap B_{r_n} (p)= B_{\min r}(p)$.

[1]Rudin defines "neighborhood" as an "open ball" with a center point $p$ and a radius $r_i$ and so the "neighborhood" at $p$ with radius, $r$, is $\{x\in X|d(x,p) < r\}$.

======

Rudin's actual proof is subtle.

Let $K$ be a compact set.  He proves $K$ is closed be proving $K^c$ is open.

He lets $p \not \in K$.

Now for any $q\in K$ then $d(q,p) > 0$ and we can find a radius $r_q < \frac 12d(q,p)$ and let $W_q = B_{r_q}(q)$.  If we do this for all $q\in K$ then $q \in W_q$ and so $K \subset \cup_{q\in K} W_q$.  So $\{W_q|q\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$.

$K$ is compact so it has a finite subcover $W_{q_1},W_{q_2}...., W_{q_n}$ and $K \subset \cup W_{q_i} = W$.

For these finite number of points $q_i$ we can find $U_{q_i}$ that are neighborhoods of $p$ with radius $r_{q_i} < \frac 12 d(q_i, p)$.

Then the intersection of the $U_{q_i}$ is $B_{\min r_{q_i}} (p)$.  If $y\in K \subset W=\subset W_{q_i}$ then $y \in W_{q_j}$ for some $W_{q_j}$ sp $d(q_j,y) < r_j < \frac 12 d(q_j,p)$

But then $d(q_j,y) + d(y,p) \ge d(q_j, p)$ so $d(y,p) \ge d(q_j,p)-d(q_j,y) \ge d(q_j,p)-d(q_j,p)=\frac 12d(d_j,p) > r_j \ge \min r_{q_i}$.

So $y \not \in B_{\min r_{q_i}}(p)$ for any $y \in K$

Co $B_{\min r_{q_i}}(p) \subset K^c$.

So $K^c$ is open.

So $K$ is closed.

=====

Comment: Thank you so much! The proof is perfectly clear now.